# SRP Rules (Group Policy) for mingw32-make

Tags: mingw32, group-policy

I have Software Restriction Policies set up on my PC. Whenever I try to use mingw32-make from the command line, I get this:

```
mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile
This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 1
Makefile:4: recipe for target `All' failed
```

In Software Restriction Policies, I have a path rule for `C:\MinGw`.
Also, if enter into the command line `mingw32-make.exe`, in a folder with no makefile, this is what I get:

```
mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

I guess ming32-make runs a secondary executable that isn't allowed under SRP.
Does anyone know what this program could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the Event Viewer keeps a record of when SRP blocks something. Using this, I found mingw32-make creates a .bat file in the user's %TEMP% folder. I then whitelisted that .bat file in SRP. It requires a wildcard since part of the .bat file's name is randomly generated.

However, this will allow any .bat file that matches the wildcard to be executed. This allows malicious files to be run if they match the wildcard.